# How to find all the files of a particular model in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Good morning. I have a task to make a request that would find all the documents of a certain type. After receiving the result, I need to display the fields of all found documents in the table. How can I do that? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what did you try? Do you call the REST-API? Please show us your sourcecode.

Comment: I'm trying to write a web script, but as soon as it came to writing a query there were problems) I recently in alfresco and Java so there are difficulties in the simplest situations

Comment: which sourcecode to show?

Comment: What problems do you have with writing the query? Please [edit] your question and include the relevant part of your model and the query you try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lucene [query](http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/07/09/alfresco-lucene-tutorial/) to find all folders of the specific type.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve all documents of a certain type you can use Lucene query, this is a working example of query to get all nodes with type `ipt:delegation` using java.

```
    String query = "TYPE:\"ipt:delegation\"";
    SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();
    StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
    sp.addStore(storeRef);
    sp.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);
    sp.setQuery(query);
    ResultSet results = null;
    try {
        results = searchService().query(sp);
        for (ResultSetRow row : results) {
            NodeRef nodeRef = row.getNodeRef();
        // do your work - 
        }
    }
```

And to retrieve document fields you can use `nodeService.getProperties(nodeRef)`.

Comment: Yes, Exact. @Kun Aguero now you can get all the nodes of the particular type as Oussama has explained.